# Navigating Plunkr code

Tags: angular, plunker

Most of the code in the Angular 2 documentation is provided through Plunkr. I find this really frustrating, because if I have a plunkr window with the example code open for a long time, it will eventually go blank and refreshing it will not bring it back--you have to find where you launched it from and launch it again. Is there a way to open the plunkr so that the parameters that launched it are persevered (ie so you could bookmark it)?

Another problem is that I don't see a way to search a Plunkr project to find where code in one file is used in other files, which really makes it hard for me to follow the flow of code. Is there a way to get back to where the files are stored (a GitHub repo or...?) so that it's possible to do such a search?

Comment: Hello? Is this really such a useless question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure how, given a plunker, you can work backward to find the repo it's connected to. I think most plunks are not connected to a repo at all.

However, when I commented on a bug at the Angular documentation GitHub repo, someone mentioned in passing that the plunks were automatically generated from GitHub when you click the link. I still haven't been able to find specifics on how this works, but it was enough for me to discover where the [GitHub files for the testing docs are](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/tree/695df679295f881935c8f7c96244cb70367056a9/public/docs/_examples/testing/ts/app). These are searchable so it's easier to follow the dependencies.